# VBA to look at cell names in a column A, open file based on that name, and copy only headers in column C:

Tags: vba

i am working on integrating a API through our erp and alteryx. To build out the API, i need to extract strictly field names from 50 some-odd files and list them out in one row per file. so lets say for example Cell A3 = '3', look for 3.xlsx in a folder and copy the top row into B3: to however many fields there are.

Kindest,
-R

Comment: What is your question? Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and note that SO is not for asking others to code your stuff

Answer (score 0):

Not tested. If your cell value only contains the name of the workbook, you will need to build your string with 3 inputs: **Location**, **File Name**, & **File Type**. Together these make up the variable `sFile` in the below code. Here, only the file name is dynamic (as determined by value in Col A).

This is dependent on all of your files being in the **same folder**. Will open the file, and copy all of the headers (top row) and paste in Col B on your sheet next to the file name.

You need to update `sPath` and how sheets are referred to (here `"Sheet"` and `"?"`). Does every book have the same sheet name that you are looking for? Does every book have just 1 sheet? Just things you will need to account for.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Tester()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim sPath As String, sFile As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim Headers As Range

sPath = "E:\YourPath\....."

Dim MyFileRange As Range, MyFile As Range
Set MyFileRange = ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each MyFile In MyFileRange
        sFile = sPath & MyFile.Text & ".xlsx"
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sFile)
            If Not wb Is Nothing Then
                Set Headers = wb.Sheets("?").Range("A1:A" & wb.Sheets("?").Cells(1, wb.Sheets("?").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)
                Headers.Copy MyFile.Offset(, 1)
                wb.Close False
            Else
                MyFile.Offset(, 1) = "WORKBOOK NOT FOUND"
            End If
    Next MyFile
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

---

Amended to handle the error of a workbook not being found. In this instance, you will see "*WORKBOOK NOT FOUND*" in Col B next to the file name.